# Mocked IPasswordHasher.HashPassword returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I have mocked `IPasswordHasher<User>>`:

```cs
private readonly Mock<IPasswordHasher<User>> _passwordHasher = new();

private readonly AccountController _accountController;

public AccountControllerTests()
{
    _accountController = new AccountController(_passwordHasher.Object);
}
```

Then I called this mocked `AccountController` inside my test method:

```cs
var result = _accountController.Login(dto);
```

And inside this method, `hash` is null, even though the `user` and `dto.Password` is not null and it works in "normal" (non-mocking) environment:

```cs
var hash = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, dto.Password);
```

Comment: Could you provide code of `IPasswordHasher` implementation?

Comment: I'm using ``IPasswordHasher`` from ``Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity``.
This is source code: https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/PasswordHasher.cs

Comment: I understand right, that it doen't work in real app?

Comment: Yes. In real app I use Dependency Injection - a scoped of ``IPasswordHasher``. 
I just found a solution. See below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the method calls for the mocked object.

In the constructor of your test class, you could for example add

```
_passwordHasher
    .Setup(m => m.HashPassword(It.IsAny<User>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns("Hash value");
```

Comment: So, what is the point of unit-testing if I have to mock every method?

I found a solution to my problem - use a ``PasswordHasher`` instead of  mocking the interface

Comment: This will work just fine, so I'll mark this as an answer. Thanks